# Java - assign different parts of a matched regex pattern to case-specific variables

Tags: java, regex

I'm creating a software piece that takes commands with certain parameters from the user, and I want to know what the best way to match the command to a set of possible patterns made by a regex module, and if a pattern is matched then the required parameters that are in the command string are assigned as variables, and possibly switching boolean variables, to be used in other methods.

At the moment, I'm using a switch statement to check the first word in the command string, but I want to move to regex to allow for more complicated command patterns.

For example, this is what my code looks like at the moment:

```
class Main{

    public static void process_cmd(String command){
    inputs = command.split(" ");
    switch(inputs[0]) //where inputs[0] is the actual command
    case "quit": System.exit(0); 
    case "connect":
        if (!inputs[1].isEmpty()) //and other parts of the string are args for the command
            doSomething(inputs[1]);
        break;
    case "blah":
        doSomethingElse(inputs[1]);
        break;
    case ...
        ...
    } 

    public static void main(String args[]){

    //loop to scan console input goes here
    process_cmd(Scanner.nextLine());

    }

}
```

I want the command to be passed to the regex module, and be able to extract information from the string using pattern matching.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: use the right tool for the job mate. This has ANTLR written all over it :)

Comment: @JustDanyul is ANTLR fast? i'm not sure how I feel about having to learn a new system right now, and I'm making a GUI language for q/kdb+ for this so it needs to be fast enough to keep up with kdb's speed

Comment: ANTLR is a parser generator written and maintained by experts. It have been used to create parsers for real world programming languages (groovy is a example of such language), so assuming that you are not a PhD level Computer Scientist parser writing expert, I think its safe to say it will offer better performance than a parser you hand write :) This is obviously just a conjecture, but you know :p

Comment: ps: it seems a ANTLR grammer already exits for Q -> http://www.markusbarchfeld.de/blog/article/2009/10/11/an_antlr_grammar_for_q.html

Comment: @JustDanyul fair enough, I'll have a look then. Can I call java methods using the regex generated? edit: I don't specifically need a grammar for q, my software will just interact with a Q server and its variables

Comment: you have absolute control. you just need to learn to use it. It will have a fairly steep learning curve, especially if this is the first time you dabble with parser generators and defining grammars, but its worth it (and its certainly the right tool for the job, considering what you want to accomplish). Start with the tutorials at antlr4.org

Comment: <feeling_frustrated>You deleted your question just after I posted an answer. I feel like I wasted my time trying to help you. </feeling_frustrated>

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sorry, I found the fix to the problem myself